# Questions Using 나요

Tags: sentence-endings, polite-speech

I have been confused about when to use 나요 for polite questions, as opposed to just (어/아/여)요.  Is there certain situations where 나요 is more appropriate to use, or is it just kind of random?

Someone I know was just telling me, and I quote,  "-나요 is used for questions where the speaker does not mind the answer to be 'No' or 'I don't know': 이 기차가 어디로 가나요? - Would you happen to know where this train is going?"

Does this sound like an accurate summation, or is it wrong, or only part of the story here?

Thanks for any help!  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Korean: A Comprehensive Grammar* links -나(요) to -ㄴ가(요)/-은가(요), with -나(요) being slightly more common for action (or as they call them, "processive") verbs. It is given the name "dubitative questions" there, which gives a hint as to how they are used. By making the speaker's attitude **doubtful** or **dubious**, it is softened (부드럽다) and so more amenable to all sorts of "polite", "professional", even "feminine" situations.

Hence I wouldn't disagree with the statement that -나(요) is used situations where there is high likelihood of a negative answer or an answer of "don't know". But I don't think it's a complete description.

There's another factor, where it is a question with a hint of "**rumination**", often but not exclusively used in self-directed questions. This fits neatly with its use in exclamations.

Hence in both these senses, it is quite like the English "I wonder" / "I was wondering" / "I've been wondering" appended to the end, despite the fact that in English people would rarely use such a phrase used in advertising.

I've noticed a tendency for -나(요) to be used for yes/no questions, possibly because it is definitely a interrogative as opposed to the standard -아/어(요) which relies a lot on intonation. However this is just a tendency, and definitely not set in stone. I surmise that it might be related to the fact that in 경상도 사투리 Gyeongsang-do dialect, -나 is one of the usual 반말 yes/no question markers, whilst -노 is its equivalent for open-ended questions. However I don't posit that there's been significant Gyeongsang-do dialect influence on standard Korean; rather they're both from Middle Korean roots.

Comment: I hate to have to choose just one answer here, my friends, but Michaelyus's succinct and clear style with scholarly references kind of takes the cake.

Comment: Would you say, that if it is "dubitative," asking a personal question could come off rude if you aren't careful?  Or at least could it be used that way?  Something like "대학교에서 졸업했나요?" maybe shouldn't asked in a "dubitative" way because wouldn't that imply you think the person is uneducated...??  See what I mean?

Comment: This is a very good answer, and I've upvoted it. However I believe both the contributor and @B.Alvn are drawing rather too much from the label 'dubitative.' If 하나요 carries 'I wonder' it could only do so by the tone. / As for 대학 졸업했나요 I don't see how in today's Korea this question can fail to offend (unless the person in question is 22 and may or may not have graduated *yet*). So taking 어제 부탁드린 일 끝냈나요? This will *no more* imply you doubt it than 끝냈어요? if the two are spoken in the same tone of straightforward inquiry. (If it helps you to evaluate the comment, this is native speaker intuition.)

Comment: @Catomic Well the meaning of the word is "expressing or inclined to doubt or hesitation." so, umm, I'm trying to dig a bit deeper here.  Perhaps that term isn't the best term.  I should also add that "in today's Korea" there are still plenty of people well above 70 years of age from rural areas that certainly wouldn't have gone to a university, if even high school, or for that matter, a Confucian academy that still existed when they were young........so ummm....let's not forgot the older generation here, ok?  :-D

Answer (score 6):

Thing about Korean is that, besides the formality stuff, your desired tone and nuances can also determine what ending you use. For instance, if I were to ask where the train is going:

> 기차가 어디로 가요?
>   기차가 어디로 가나요?
>   기차가 어디로 갈까요?

All three forms are technically possible (I'll explain the 3rd one in a bit).

The difference between first and second is in your tone/nuance, not the meaning or setting. The first one is just an informal 존댓말 - you are asking someone who seems of your age but is a stranger. The second one means the same thing and can be used in identical situations, *but* delivers a "kinder" tone. The ending has a bit of feminine touch to it; I personally picture a kindergarten teacher talking to her students in this manner. (Adults sometimes use 존댓말 to babies for, I guess, educational purposes).

So there is no definite distinction between the first and second ending. There's no such situation in which you have to use 나요.

I added the third one there just to show how endings can carry more utilities than just "formal/informal settings." When you ask a question using ~까요, you're essentially assuming either of you don't know the question and is stirring up a discussion.

Comment: +1 for extending the comparison with 갈까요?

Comment: My understanding of interrogatives in (으)ㄹ까(요) are that you are asking someone's "opinion" more or less, isn't that right?  So that definitely seems very non-confrontational and soft..."In your opinion" or "Do you think" but would this really be typically used for a simple data request about a train?  Seems more appropriate (I've long thought) for opinions with deeper answers, as you say, to start a discussion perhaps..

Comment: @B.Alvn No, typically one wouldn't start a discussion on the destination of the train he is in. I was just trying to stay within the same topic lol Though I guess it could be used in like a math problem per se.

Comment: @Posh_Pumpkin  a math problem?  huh?

Comment: @B.Alvn Like ~까(요) could be used when asking about a train's destination in the context of a math problem.

Answer (score 5):

I reworked the answer. Deleted anything doubtful, confusing or not on point.  Added a segment on 'generality.'

---

Doubt.

Upshot:

- Both '하나요?' and '해요?' can be straightforward inquiry implying no expectation of the answer going one way or the other.
- '해요?' is suitable for signaling an expectation or desire to confirm. (Note: This is nothing special about '해요?' Most forms of question are.)  '하나요?' much less.
- Thus, '해요?' would have a better claim to be called 'confirmatory' than '하나요?' has to 'dubitative.'  (On this term of grammar, see the answer by Michaelyus.)

Example. In reference to some event you did not attend, either of

> 끝났어요?  (Has it ended?)
>   끝났나요?

can be straightforward inquiry that signals nothing but your desire to know.  You don't appear to think the answer would go one way or the other.

However, if people are streaming out of the conference room, and you are asking someone merely to confirm, you would say the first of:

> 끝났어요?
>   <strike>끝났나요?</strike>

Yes, you can force '끝났나요?' into that job by giving it the right tone, but it would not sound as good.

Therefore if '끝났나요?' is 'dubitative', it is *not* in always signaling doubt, but in being *un*suitable for an expression of expectation or desire to confirm.

---

Another example on doubt.

Suppose you were somewhere and your sister was to join you shortly.  You want to tell her to bring the car, but your mom answering the phone says she already left.  Here, which of

> 차 갖고 갔어요?  (Did she take the car?)
>   차 갖고 갔나요?

will come out may be 'random' for most people (barring e.g. subtle aesthetic preferences).  In any event, neither would imply more doubt or expectation than the other.

But suppose your sister was in the habit of taking your car, and you suspect this has happened again.  Barging in at the door you say to your mother:

> 걔 또 차 갖고 갔어요?
>   <strike>걔 또 차 갖고 갔나요?</strike>

Here you are far more likely to say the first.

(I have scrapped the bus driver example as raising unrelated questions.)

---

Generality.

Upshot:

- Both '해요?' and '하나요? may refer to a particular person and event.
- For generalities, '하나요?' is more likely.

Example.  Either of

> 할아버지는 언제 결혼하셨어요? (Grandpa, when did you get married?)
>   할아버지는 언제 결혼하셨나요?

will be OK.

But of

> <strike>조선시대에는 보통 몇 살에 결혼했어요?</strike>
>   조선시대에는 보통 몇 살에 결혼했나요? (In the Josun era, at what age did people generally marry?)

the latter sounds much better.

Don't let the reference to the Josun dynasty make you think this is a case of doubt.  The question might be about some procedure.  If you are asking some contractor how *he* handles an engineering situation, either of

> 이런 경우에는 주로 어떤 자재를 써요? (In this case, usually which material would be used?)
>   이런 경우에는 주로 어떤 자재를 쓰나요?

may do.

But if the question is about orthodoxy, then the second is more likely:

> <strike>이런 경우에는 주로 어떤 자재를 써요?</strike>
>   이런 경우에는 주로 어떤 자재를 쓰나요?

Note:  I may be condensing many variables into 'generality,' and more examples might bring out further subtleties.

---

A caveat.

You must not think that '하나?' is related to '하나요?' in the same way '해?' is to '해요?'

Between '해?' and '해요? (e.g. '갔어?' and '갔어요?') there is only the difference of familiarity or respect.

But '하나?' is wholly different from '하나요?'

'하나?' can be one of these three things (possibly others).

- Expression of moderate respect.  A mother-in-law might use it to address her son-in-law, or a professor a graduate student, and in old movies educated men each other.
- A question spoken as if in soliloquy.  Here it means something like (and is probably an elided version of), '하나 봐' or '하나 몰라.'
- In poetry, something like exclamation.

I.e., just because you know when to say '했나요?' you cannot just drop '요' and get a familiar version.

---

-나요 and -가요.

These are equivalent, the choice depending only on phonetic considerations.  I am placing them among certain possibly related forms for reference.

-나요

> 답이 맞다. (The answer is right--*base form*.)
>   답이 맞아.  (The answer is right.)
>   답이 맞아요.  (The answer is right.)
>   답이 맞아?  (Is the answer right?)
>   답이 맞아요?  (Is the answer right?)
>   답이 맞나 보다. (The answer seems right--*base form; this sentence could have other meanings*.)
>   답이 맞나 확인하다. (Null-subject ascertains whether the answer is right--*base form*.)
>   답이 맞나? (Is the answer right?)
>   답이 맞나요? (Is the answer right?)

-가요

> 개가 어리다. (The dog is young--*base form*.)
>   개가 어려.  (The dog is young.)
>   개가 어려요.  (The dog is young.)
>   개가 어려?  (Is the dog young?)
>   개가 어려요?  (Is the dog young?)
>   개가 어린가 보다. (The dog seems young--*base form; this sentence could have other meanings*.)
>   개가 어린가 확인하다. (Null-subject ascertains whether the dog is young--*base form*.)
>   개가 어린가? (Is the dog young?)
>   개가 어린가요? (Is the dog young?)

Comment: Are you theorizing that 나요  may be a contraction of 나 보다 (seems like) with 요 added for politeness? I think this makes sense...Because "does it seem like?" is not so committing of a question to answer.  However, if this is the case, why would it have to be a question?  In fact, 나 is sometimes used as a declarative ending, isn't it?

Comment: No. A question and a statement. How can one be a contraction of the other? Notice that there is no 보다 in 했나요? It's more like *That/whether the answer is right* + 요. But I am not saying that this is what goes on in the mind of a native speaker. He does not have to analyze anything.

Comment: Then I don't fully understand what you mean by "derives from" ..  By "contraction" I simply mean that the 보다 part is removed, maybe unconsciously or from long-term repeated use, kind of thing...

Comment: It's a speculation about a common origin from common morphology. This happens all the time. (If some language has similar looking indicative past and subjunctive present you can wonder about their potential common origin.) Maybe you should just forget my commentary, and try to get comfortable with what's in the yellow boxes, which is raw data.

Comment: There is nothing in those boxes that makes me uncomfortable.  I can see exactly where you are coming from here.  I was just curious about your speculation, because I think you are not just casually interested in this area, nor am I.

Comment: @B.Alvn I'm glad it made sense. I cannot think of any -나 ending that is declarative though.

Comment: Well, let's see if anyone can answer my question directly, eh?  Perhaps this is a harder question than I thought.  What is a "bounty"?

Comment: According to this (http://blogs.transparent.com/korean/verb-ending-3/) 나요 can be used for exclamations as well as questions...so I'm going to guess that 나 can be too, and that is what I saw, only without exclamation marks...I've definitely seen this in advertising like on signs or billboards, where 요 wouldn't be used of course..

Comment: @B.Alvn. Yes, any question form can be an exclamation in the right tone and  context; and 했나 and 했나요 are no exception. If that's all they have in mind, the blog entry is misleading. If their claims is that 했나 or 했나요 is specifically a form of exclamation, that would be downright wrong.

Comment: I tried to give your question a direct answer. See as amended.

Comment: Come to think of it, 하나! or 했던가! is often used in poetic apostrophe, but never 하나요.

Comment: @B.Alvn I just want to comment on "나요" being a contraction of "나보다+요". It's not. "답이 맞나 봐요?" captures the tone and meaning of "답이 맞나 보다" better. It's basically saying, "The answer's correct, right?" On the other hand, "답이 맞나요?" means "Is the answer correct?" Do you see the difference?

Comment: @Catomic  I can see I will have to read all of this a few more times, but thanks for adding all that stuff.  It's bewildering because you have edited your answer at least 12 times now...nothing personal or anything, and I'm grateful for your input, but to be a bit frank, I think you are just "winging it" on this particular question...and therefore I'm feeling a little unsure myself of the whole story....  Of course it is standard knowledge that this ending is "gentle" that much is a given.  I'm sorry but I gave the check to the answer below because he seems much more authoritative and direct

Comment: One more comment...I don't think, after vast bus-riding experience in Korea, that anyone is using the honorific 세요 ask a bus driver...I've never heard it or even been suggested to use it by tourist helpers who have given me direct questions to ask bus drivers.  Furthermore, I don't think that it is the proper use of adding the honorific, because it's really not directly about the driver, it's about the bus. It's just not that personal.  If it was normal I would have heard it many times and I often sit near the front of the bus, too.... :)

Comment: Furthermore, 아저씨 isn't even considered polite language and if you are going to address someone as honored with 시/세 like that, you'd use 선생님 most likely, no?

Comment: @B.Alvn. I am always winging it on any answer in the sense of trying to gather and articulate my sense of what is going on. Thus the answer might end up with a look of a progress report, as in this case. / You are right that the most likely thing shouted to a bus driver is 동대문 가요? by someone on the pavement who knows the poor guy is anxious to leave, and without any address like 아저씨. But if you should start with 아저씨 then it would be proper to use honorifics. It is distinguishable from 'department store honorifics' like 이건 할인 안 되세요.

Comment: Whether 아저씨 is an honorific might well end up being a debate about what an 'honorific' is rather than 아저씨. Terms like 아저씨, 아줌마, 젊은이, 새댁 used to be wholly unexceptional, but now many sociological issues are raised around them, not only by feminists etc. who don't want to be called 아줌마 or 아가씨 but also by 아줌마 who wouldn't mind being called 아가씨. / If you called a bus driver 선생님, that might be a kind thing to do on that occasion, but would contribute to the perception that there was anything the matter with 아저씨, 아줌마 etc.

Comment: On your last question, let us forget the bus driver (who is anxious to leave), but consider 수위 아저씨 (guard) at an apartment complex. To him 아저씨 우체국이 어딨는지 아세요 or 아시나요 would be wholly appropriate. Again 선생님 might be a kindness to him on that day, but I disapprove of it as a trend, as implying that there was anything wrong with 아저씨.

Comment: @B.Alvn. I've reworked the thing extensively and made many of the comments obsolete. I wonder if we shouldn't delete them.

Comment: quite frankly, we have veered far off on a tangent and I'm partly responsible.  Let's just kind of drop it.  But I strongly feel that just 어요 is enough for a bus driver, because you are *talking about the bus, not the driver* see what I mean?

Comment: wow!   your reworking is, as we say, "off the hook".....!!!!!!!  :-DDDD

Comment: @B.Alvn. On our poor bus driver, yes '동대문 가요?' is enough because he will *choose* to interpret it as affecting the bus. If you say '동대문 가세요?' then he will have no (grammatical) choice but to read it as affecting himself.

Comment: the poor guy...anyways, it is kind of surprising that the Korean Tourist Information (Bureau or whatever it is...) told me to use "가요" and not "가세요 or 가시나요" isn't it?  Do they hate bus drivers or something?

Comment: @Catomic Feel free to delete any and all comments that are superfluous here, including this one...

Comment: @B.Alvn. I believe you said you've used many grammar books? Is there one you would say was the best?  Whether presented in Korean or English.  (This thread being so long I am now using it to get in contact with you. It's the 어짜피 버린 몸 ideology.)

Comment: @Catomic  I prefer Korean Grammar For International Learners myself...it's main drawback is that there is no guidance between contemporary forms and rarer and even borderline archaic grammar items, of which it contains quite a lot.  At least it does NOT use Romanization, and it gives a lot of example sentences, and the English is very clear and easy to understand even for a non-linguist.

Comment: @Catomic  How'd you like a medium sized project, just for fun and games?  I'm working on a kind of dialog (or play) thing and trying really hard to write it in completely natural Korean...It would probably take you 15 or 20 minutes to read through but you might enjoy it and find some interesting or humorous language puzzles in it.......no pressure or anything but do you wanna take a look??

Comment: @B.Alvn. I don't know I want to undertake a project (constitutionally against it), but I will look at it. Where is it?

Comment: on my computer.  oh you don't have to, i just kind of thought you might have a lot of free time for this kind of thing, and that you might think it was fun....

Comment: @B.Alvn. I am happy to look at it. Just commenting on 'project.' Thought you might have it up on a blog or something. Just tell me how I can access it.

Comment: @Catomic can I just email it to you?  Or share the document on Google docs, or something like that?

Comment: @B.Alvn. Maybe you lost interest in the idea? I will delete the email address in a few days.

Comment: @Catomic  delete it!  I wrote it down, just want to polish it up a little more, probably today, and then I will send it over...pdf file ok?  or?

Comment: @B.Alvn. OK. However and whenever you want to do it.

Comment: @Catomic  I just sent it over, the first two "scenes" (It's meant to be a kind of play)...